# sorting across sheets in excel

Tags: sorting, vba, excel, dynamic-linking

I don't know if this is possible or not.

I have a workbook that has two sheets, "input" and "output"

user1 fills in the "input sheet"

Column A = name
Column B = Age
Column C = Location
Column D = Hight
..
..

Then on the "output" sheet Column A is set to copy the value from Column A on the "input" sheet and User2 fills in more details using the values that user1 has entered

Column B = eye colour
Column C = hair colour
Column D = number of fingers
..
..

So I hope you get the idea, User1 enters some details, and then User2 does some work with that and enters more details in the "output sheet. With Column A being the "index" value that links the two together.

My issue is that if User2 enters there details, and then goes back to the "input" sheet and preforms a sort, the values in the "output" sheet will no longer match, as while Column A will have changes to reflect the sort operation the rest will stay the same.

Is it possible to link rows between sheets, or to create a sort code that will run across both sheets and keep them consistence.

This does not have to work for ad-hoc searches that the user tries, I just want to put a button on the "input" sheet, for example to "sort by name", "sort by Location" etc

Regards

Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ok with having pre-set sorts, one solution is to mirror both values from sheet A and sheet B to sheet C, and then just sort that, and re-populate the values in sheet A and B with the new, sorted, results.

I.e.

```
Sheet1                   | Sheet 2                           | Sheet 3 (Hidden and named)
                         |                                   | 
Name     Age    etc,     | Eye Colour    Hair colour   etc.  | =Sheet1!A1 ... =Sheet2!A1
```

Then your sort button would call a sub something like:

```
Dim rngSortRange As Range, rngStartCell As Range, rngEndCell As Range
Set rngStartCell = Worksheets("Sheet_3_Name_Goes_Here").Range("A1")
Set rngEndCell = Worksheets("Sheet_3_Name_Goes_Here").Range( _
  rngStartCell.End(xlToRight).Column, _
  rngStartCell.End(xlDown).Row)
Set rngSortRange = Worksheets("Sheet_3_Name_Goes_Here").Range(rngStartCell, rngEndCell)
rngSortRange.Sort Key1:=<Column Number Here>, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
rngSortRange.Range(rngStartCell, _
                    Worksheets("Sheet_3_Name_Goes_Here").Range( _
                     Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column, _
                     rngEndCell.Row _
                    ) _
                   ).Copy
Worksheets("Sheet 1").Paste
rngSortRange.Range(Worksheets("Sheet_3_Name_Goes_Here").Range(
                     rngStartCell.Column + Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column, _
                     rngStartCell.Row _
                    ), _
                    rngEndCell _
                   ).Copy
Worksheets("Sheet 2").Paste
```

That might need some work (e.g. you might need to reset sheet3 afterwards, you might need to pastevalues rather than just paste, else you'll end up pasting self-referencing formulas), but the basic idea should work.

Comment: I looked at this but for waht I want so much code and to inflexible if it ever needs changing