# Microsoft Excel invert columns order with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have large table with columns of dates : `1 january, 2 january, 3 january ...`

But now it's crucial not to scroll right cause of big data.

My idea is to invert columns:`27 june, 26 june ... 1 january`

And after that paste column with new date at the left.

Is any tool to invert columns in default MS Excel or in VBA ?

Comment: Copy it, paste special and transpose, sort by your column, then copy/transpose back.

Comment: Thank you! Not ideal way, but worked. I think VBA can do this, did you saw some VBA script library ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sorting across sheets in excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818776/sorting-across-sheets-in-excel)

Answer (score 1):

You could use this script from previous accepted answer about sorting columns across sheets:
[Sort excel columns across sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371185/sort-excel-columns-across-sheets/24374926#24374926)

First create a new sheet as first in workbook. Then add columns headers with dates in desired order: 27 june... 1 june

Replace number of columns and number of sheets in script

Save a backup before running this macro, no undo.

After rearrangement delete first sheet

```
Sub ColumnRearrangement()
  'Horaciux 2014-06-23
Dim nextLabel As String
Dim currentLabel As String

Dim TotalPages As Integer
Dim TotalColumns As Integer

TotalPages = 10
TotalColumns = 200

'Insert a blank column in each page
For p = 2 To TotalPages
    Sheets(p).Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("B1").Select
Next

For c = TotalColumns To 1 Step -1
    Sheets(1).Select

    'Debug.Print "-" & Cells(1, c).Text & "-" & Str(c)
    nextLabel = Cells(1, c).Text
    Sheets(2).Select
    For oldCulumn = 2 To TotalColumns + 1

        'Debug.Print Cells(1, oldCulumn).Text & "-" & Str(oldCulumn)
        currentLabel = Cells(1, oldCulumn).Text

        If currentLabel = nextLabel Then
            'Debug.Print currentLabel & "-" & Str(oldCulumn)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    For p = 2 To TotalPages
        Sheets(p).Select
        Columns(oldCulumn).Select
        Selection.Cut
        Columns("A:A").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Next
Next

For p = 2 To TotalPages
    Sheets(p).Select
    Range("A1").Select
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: @SergeySenkov Does it work for you? Could you formally accept this answer?